# Cannot send email from PHP using gmail SMTP

Tags: php, ssl, gmail

I tried to send messages from wordpress using gmail SMTP.

Server is set to **smtp.gmail.com** and port to **465**.

I'm getting this message:

> ```
> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the
> ```
>
> socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you
>   configured PHP? (34225384)

I'm on centOS

Should I recompile PHP and just enable something somewhere ?

Comment: You will likely need the [openssl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) to be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) hasn't been installed/enabled. Check `phpinfo()` for mentions of openssl, if it's not there you might need to re-compile with openssl support or enable the extension in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the `;` in front of the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your php.ini?